# Rails 4. How show movies list where purchases is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 # Movie Model
 has_many :purchases
 has_many :buyers, through: :purchases

 # User Model
 has_many :purchases, foreign_key: :buyer_id
 has_many :movies, through: :purchases

 # Purchase Model
 belongs_to :movie
 belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/build-online-store-rails/

How show movies list where purchases is nil?

Comment: You mean, you want to show movies without associated purchases?

Comment: Yes i want to show movies without associated purchases